# Javascript firebase storage Cannot read property 'child' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi i'm currently following the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) to get image from firebase storage and showing it in my html per logged in userId

index.html:

```
<script src="scripts/config.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/auth.js"></script>
```

config.js:

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "quickstart-xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://quickstart-xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxx-xxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "1:xxxxxx:web:xxxxx",
    measurementId: "x-xxxxxx"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

const storage = firebase.storage();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

auth.js:

```
console.log(`test/${user.uid}/profile-pic.jpg`);
    storage.storageRef.child(`test/${user.uid}/profilepic.jpg`).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
          $("#pic").attr("src", url);
    }).catch(function(error) {
          console.error(error);
    });
```

But i'm currently getting the following error:

> auth.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of
>   undefined

I'm sure that the parameter i put in child() had a value by console log:

```
console.log(`test/${user.uid}/profile-pic.jpg`);
```

show the current string with the logged in userID:

> test/dtrNGt9usCSqwV86BfKnw6SjWHb2/profile-pic.jpg

I double check the docs to see if i wrote anything wrong but doesn't seem to find any.

I also check the path to the file on my firebase storage and it's indeed in the test folder

[image]
Hope someone can tell me what wrong with my code

Comment: what is undefined is `storage.storageRef` not your string. can you try log it ?

Comment: @Crocsx it returned `undefined`, why is that ? i defined `const storage = firebase.storage();` in my config.js and i used `storage.storageRef` in my auth.js and auth.js is under config.js in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh i found out, i though storageRef was a function but it's a reference to the folder. I changed it to this and now it worked:

```
storage.ref(`test/${user.uid}/profilepic.jpg`).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
   $("#pic").attr("src", url);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
);
```